# How can I differentiate between two alphabets of the same language in HTML?

Tags: html, internationalization

Are there means besides the `lang="..."` attribute in HTML to differentiate between Latin, Cyrillic alphabet of Montenegrin, Uzbek, Interslavic and other languages that can be found in multiple alphabets?

For instance, I see that there is an only one ISO code for both Latin and Cyrillic variants of Montenegrin (`cnr`), which is not very convenient in cases where you want explicitly distinguish in HTML markup between both variants.

What can I do semantically in HTML to separate paragraphs written in different alphabets of the same language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have managed to find what to do in such cases.

**tl;dr**: `sr-Latn-RS` represents Serbian (`sr`) written using Latin (`Latn`) as used in Serbia (`RS`).

See more details here:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-2.2.3

> Script subtags are used to indicate the script or writing system
>      variations that distinguish the written forms of a language or its
>      dialects.  The following rules apply to the script subtags:
>
> 1. Script subtags MUST follow any primary and extended language
>         subtags and MUST precede any other type of subtag.
> 2. **Script subtags consist of four letters and were defined according
>         to the assignments found in [ISO15924]** ("Information and
>         documentation -- Codes for the representation of names of
>         scripts"), or subsequently assigned by the ISO 15924 registration
>         authority or governing standardization bodies.  Only codes
>         assigned by ISO 15924 will be considered for registration.
> 3. The script subtags 'Qaaa' through 'Qabx' are reserved for private
>         use in language tags.  These subtags correspond to codes reserved
>         by ISO 15924 for private use.  These codes MAY be used for non-
>         registered script values.  Please refer to Section 4.6 for more
>         information on private use subtags.
> 4. There MUST be at most one script subtag in a language tag, and
>         the script subtag SHOULD be omitted when it adds no
>         distinguishing value to the tag or when the primary or extended
>         language subtag's record in the subtag registry includes a
>         'Suppress-Script' field listing the applicable script subtag.